# I'm trying to connect to Bitfinex API v2 with signed key. All I get is response error 500

Tags: vb.net

It is called with Bitfinex.QueryPrivate("orders")
I've tried without serializing the body, and with serializing the signature and the nonce - same 500 response error every time.

I've struggeled for days with this, and would appreciate any help a lot.

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Net
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
Imports System.Security.Cryptography

'Gets API data 
Public Class Bitfinex
    'Read only keys
    Private Shared Key As String = "MvHLTsSApwqnSKXYIGvnWWOC8koPoJDxXBoWCj2bZ0g"
    Private Shared SecretKey As String = "MyPrivateKey"
    Private Shared Version As String = "v2"
    Private Shared Url As String = "https://api.bitfinex.com/"

    Public Shared Function QueryPrivate(Method As String) As String
        Dim Body = ""
        Dim JsonBody = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Body)
        Dim Nonce As String = ((Date.UtcNow - New DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalMilliseconds).ToString
        Dim Path As String = String.Format("{0}/auth/r/{1}", Version, Method)
        Dim Address As String = Url & Path

        Dim SignatureString As String = "/api/" & Path & Nonce & JsonBody
        Dim Signature = GetSignature(SignatureString, SecretKey)

        Try
            Dim wc As New WebClient()
            wc.Headers.Add("bfx-nonce", Nonce)
            wc.Headers.Add("bfx-apikey", Key)
            wc.Headers.Add("bfx-signature", Signature)
            wc.Headers.Add("content-type", "application/json")
            'wc.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "My Bitfinex agent")
            Return wc.UploadString(Address, JsonBody)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return "0"
        End Try
        Return ""
    End Function

    Private Shared Function GetSignature(SignatureString As String, SecretKey As String) As String
        Dim SecretKeyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SecretKey)

        Using myHMAC As New HMACSHA384(SecretKeyBytes)
            Dim SignatureBytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SignatureString)
            Dim SignatureHash = myHMAC.ComputeHash(SignatureBytes)
            Return System.BitConverter.ToString(SignatureHash).ToLower().Replace("-", String.Empty)
        End Using
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: [**HTTP status code 500**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) is called _Internal Server Error_, which is an error on the server's side. I don't think there's anything you can do about it other than to contact their support.

Comment: Infact you might even want to ask this on their [**GitHub page**](https://github.com/bitfinexcom/bitfinex-api-node/issues) instead. That will get you in touch directly with the devs, and they should be able to see if you've done something wrong or if the issue is on their side (it's not certain that they understand VB.NET however, so you might have to describe what your code does as well).

Comment: @VisualVincent  I thought it strange that I got this error since my public call to the same adress works. I'll follow your advice and contact them at their GitHub page. Thanks.

Comment: Well there can be a lot of reasons why the public API works and the private doesn't. Every existing piece of code can fail exactly anywhere, so there's really no _"if this works then that should as well"_ when it comes to programming. ;)

Comment: It turned out to be a stupid error. I've used the API key in Coinigy, and they probably multiply the nonce by 1000. Hence, my nonce was to small. Still don't understand why I didn't get a proper error in return, but that doesn't matter now... 

And sorry for my "charming english", it's not my native language...

Comment: Your english is fine ;). Glad you got it sorted out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nonce was to small. See comments.